# How I can use case statment in BIP after where as paramter?

Tags: oracle, plsql, bi-publisher

How I can use case `statment` in BIP App  after where and compare it to a date
if is the date is null show Full data if he ask for Specific date display the data for the date that he asked for

Comment: Please include sample data and expected results. How is this scenario different in BI Publisher compared to regular SQL? How is PL/SQL programming involved?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understand the question  but if you think of using case in where clause it could be something like this:

```sql
--  ...
WHERE
    something = CASE 
                    WHEN Nvl(date_column, To_Date('01.01.2099', 'dd.mm.yyyy') <= other_date_column -- or parameter or date calculation .....    
                    THEN something 
                ELSE 
                    something_else 
                END
--  ...
```

It depends what you want to do when one of comparing dates is null, but if it is null, you could use Nvl() function to create a date that is for sure out of scope and make it '=' or '<=' or '>=' or ... to the comparing value. This way you can manage the expresion and do the job. This is definitely sql question. Regards...